# php static properties and methods

Tags: php, methods, properties, static

define as follows

```
class Timer{
    private static $timeRemaining;
    private static $timeLimit;
    private static $nextTime;

    static function block();
    static function updateCookies();
}
```

when going around between webpages, how long do those static properties and methods live?
As a result, which one is better, using the class above or a singleton object?

Comment: Related: [Who needs singletons?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4596323/862594)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They live as much as PHP executes a code - while request lives.

And of course, between webpages all data is erased.
But you can use session and manually assign data to static variables or non-static instance variables.

Singletons use a static variable as a storage of instance.

Comment: You've explained them clearly enough, but I'd like to ask would it be robust if I use session in the class's destructor? like __destructor{$_SESSION['time_remaining'] = $timeRemaining;} ???

Comment: It is possible, of course, but I'd recommend you using it in constructor instead : D